# Function to PDF using FPDF error: "Not enough horizontal space to render a single character"

Tags: function, class, while-loop, google-colaboratory, fpdf

First my class and class-function code:

```
class Dataframe1: 
  def __init__(self, Date, Email, Name) 
   self.Date = Date
   self.Email = Email 
   self.Name = Name 


  def FunctionDF1(self):
        if self.Date != "":
          pdf.multi_cell(0, 5, "Date: {a}".format(a= self.Date))
        elif self.Date == "":
         pass
        else:
          pdf.multi_cell(0, 5, "Error")
        if self.Name !="": 
         pdf.multi_cell(0 , 5, "/nName{a}".format(a= self.Name))
        elif self.Name == "": 
          pass
        else:
         pdf.multi_cell(0 , 5, "/nError")
        if self.Email !="": 
         pdf.multi_cell(0 , 5, "/nEmail{a}".format(a= self.Email))
        elif self.Email == "": 
         pass
        else:
         pdf.multi_cell(0, 5, "/nError")
```

This gives no errors.

When I try to call it later, to write a PDF it does give errors.

```
i=1
while i< End1: 
  Data1 = Dataframe1(dataframe[0][i], dataframe[1][i], dataframe[2][i])
 
  class PDF(FPDF):
            def header(self):
                # Logo
                %cd /content/drive/MyDrive/Code/Intake
                self.image('image.png', 100, 8, 33, 33)
                self.set_font('Arial', '', 15)
                self.cell(80)
                #line break 
                self.ln(20)

            # Page footer
            def footer(self):
                self.set_y(-15)
                # Arial italic 8
                self.set_font('Arial', 'I', 8)
                # Page number
                #self.cell(0, 5,  u'Page ' + str(self.page_no()) + '/{nb}', 'C')

  # Go to the folder with NOTO_SANS and import it. 
  %cd /content/drive/MyDrive/code/
  pdf = PDF(format = "letter")
  pdf.alias_nb_pages()
  pdf.add_page()
  #pdf.add_font('Noto_Sans', fname=r"Noto_Sans", uni=True)
  base_Noto_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/code/Noto_Sans'
  pdf.add_font('Noto', '', os.path.join(base_Noto_path, 'NotoSans-Regular.ttf'))
  pdf.add_font('Noto', 'B', os.path.join(base_Noto_path, 'NotoSans-Bold.ttf'))
  pdf.set_font('Noto', '', 12)
  pdf.multi_cell(0, 5, u'\n\n')
  pdf.multi_cell(0, 5, u'Please contact Toll Free: \nor    our International Texting Message number is: \nPlease email us \nThank you! \n \n')
  #Not outputting the right stuff. 
  Data1.FunctionDF1()
  i = i+1

%cd /content/drive/MyDrive/code/Intake       
pdf.output('Initial_Intake_{A}_{B}.pdf'.format(A=Data1.Name, B=i))
```

The error is occurring on the line

```
Data1.FunctionDF1()
```

```
FPDFException: Not enough horizontal space to render a single character
```

Some difficulties encountered included formatting.
Other difficulties were getting it to output properly. Currently, all of the PDF outputs show the correct naming format, and show the manually added `multi_cells` but DO NOT show the function called `multi_cells`.

I was trying to output the function into the built pdf using `fpdf.multi_cell()` to write all the patient's data (unless blank) on a new line. I used a `while i<End1:` to loop through the patients and write their individual data on a different PDF.

```
  def FunctionDF1(self):
        if self.Date != "":
          print("Date: {a}".format(a= self.Date))
        elif self.Date == "":
         pass
        else:
          print("Error")
        if self.Name !="": 
         print("/nName{a}".format(a= self.Name))
        elif self.Name == "": 
          pass
        else:
         print("/nError")
        if self.Email !="": 
         print("/nEmail{a}".format(a= self.Email))
        elif self.Email == "": 
         pass
        else:
         print("/nError")
```

I tried `print()` as shown above instead of `multi_cell` in the function. It worked to display the correct information, but it showed all patient data at once when called.

The trick I'm not understanding is how do I write ONLY one patient's data to the corresponding intake form PDF.

I wonder if there are better tools than a while loop for this.

Answer (score 0):

I found that my main error was that I needed to specify

```
pdf.multi_cell(100,5,"Text")
```

When the width was no longer 0, the code did not throw an error anymore.

This did have the side effect of giving odd spacing to the PDF.